# R not updating field based on criteria

Tags: r

i have a simple DF:

```
Dev_Func   
agn   
agn   
ttt   
ttt   
agn
```

all i am trying to do is if the field contains "agn" replace it with "PE"

this is the code that i have written:

```
test = subset(Final.ds,Device_Function == "AGN" | Device_Function ==   
"TTT", select = c(Device_Function))
colnames(test) = c("Device_Function")
as.character(test)
test = within(test, Device_Function[Device_Function == 'AGN'] = 'PE')
```

but i just keep on geting this error:

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, Device_Function == "AGN", value = "PE") :
invalid factor level, NA generated
```

and all it does is replaces all the "AGN" values with NA.
help please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with `gsub`:

```
df$Dev_Func <- gsub("agn", "PE", df$Dev_Func)

df

#  Dev_Func
#1       PE
#2       PE
#3      ttt
#4      ttt
#5       PE
```

An alternative solution to keeping `Dev_Func` as a factor (as mentioned by akrun):

```
df$Dev_Func <- as.factor(gsub("agn", "PE", df$Dev_Func))

class(df$Dev_Func)

[1] "factor"
```

Answer (score 2):

As the column is a `factor`, we can assign the `levels` that are 'agn' to 'PE'

```
levels(DF$Dev_Func)[levels(DF$Dev_Func)=='agn'] <- 'PE'
```

and keep it as a `factor` column

```
levels(DF$Dev_Func)
#[1] "PE"  "ttt"

DF
#   Dev_Func
#1       PE
#2       PE
#3      ttt
#4      ttt
#5       PE
```

NOTE: Assuming that 'agn' is a fixed match and not a substring

---

In the OP's code, i.e. `within` function, there are some issues

1) the assignment is `<-` instead of `=`

2) it cannot do a logical subset assignment

3) the column is `factor` and doesn't have any level 'PE' which generates the warning message about `invalid factor level, NA generated`

4) According to the example the 'agn' is lower case and not 'AGN' (could be a typo), but `R` is case-sensitive

Suppose, we add the `PE` as `levels`

```
 DF$Dev_Func <- factor(DF$Dev_Func, levels = c(levels(DF$Dev_Func), 'PE'))
```

then the assignment below would work

```
 DF$Dev_Func[DF$Dev_Func=='agn'] <- 'PE'
```

It is still not a cleaner way compared to change based on `levels` assignment

#### data

```
DF <- structure(list(Dev_Func = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("agn", 
"ttt"), class = "factor")), .Names = "Dev_Func", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```